# Exporting a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am doing some prototyping and so created a database with a few tables and dependencies. The project became bigger than I thought and now want to clean up the names, dependencies etc and so want to create the DB anew. But I don't want to go through the whole process of creating individual tables again, instead I want to start with what I have, clean the creation scripts up and run them if possible. Is there a way I can export all the scripts to create the DB and tables? Are there tools or mysql command line options to do this?

Thanks,

-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can get you started:

`mysqldump -u user -ppassword -h host --no-create-db --no-data [other options] old_database > dump.sql`

then you can edit the dump file for any necessary changes and import back into the new database:

`mysql -u user -ppassword -h host new_database < dump.sql`

More information about the `mysqldump` @[MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to look at [MySql WorkBench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

It can do everything you need

[Here's](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/features.html) the list of all the features

> Reverse Engineer from Live Database
>
> Reverse Engineer from SQL Script

Also, good to mention that it's free (community version)